# How to use lists in dataframe to extract dictionary values using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, mapping

I am wondering about some code.
I have a dictionary example:

```
{@abc_1 : 4, @joly_55 : 3, @ttt_13 : 5, ... , @ddd_49: 500, 
'@ccc_3' : 12, '@juju_7' : 50, '@ttt_13' : 7}
```

I have a data frame like this:

```
index              name_list
0       ['@abc_1', '@joly_55', ... , '@ddd_49']
1       ['@ccc_3', '@juju_7', ... , ']
2
3
...
```

and the problem is the map method I tried didn't work.
How would I modify my dataframe to appear like this:

```
index              name_list                         magazine_map
  0       ['@abc_1', '@joly_55', ... ,'@ddd_49']    [4, 3, ... , 500]
  1       ['@ccc_3', '@juju_7', ... , '@ttt_13']    [12, 50, ... , 7] 
 ...
```

What code do I need to generate the above output?

Comment: You should always show what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using apply:

```
d = {'@abc_1' : 4, '@joly_55' : 3, '@ttt_13' : 5, '@ddd_49': 500, '@ccc_3' : 12, '@juju_7' : 50, '@ttt_13' : 7}
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'name_list' : [['@abc_1', '@joly_55', '@ttt_13', '@ddd_49'], ['@ccc_3': 12, '@juju_7']]}

df3['magazine_map'] = df3['name_list'].apply(lambda x: [d[y] for y in x])
df3
```

Output:

```
                                  namel    magazine_map
0  [@abc_1, @joly_55, @ttt_13, @ddd_49]  [4, 3, 7, 500]
1                     [@ccc_3, @juju_7]        [12, 50]
```